# Play GIF smoothly same as yeay app

Tags: android, animated-gif

I have converted Video to GIF using AnimatedGIFEncoder and getting frames for GIF, but it is not working smoothly like YEAY app and NSGIF Library of iOS. I want to play GIF smoothly like play video. What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: like YEAY app ? Really ? is this the question?

Comment: Playt GIF image use this library https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gif Loading library in Android for that. Below are some of it:

- https://github.com/Cutta/GifView
- https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

If you are using Glide, Then with glide also, You can load gif by keeping it in your raw folder in your application and use it like below:

```
ImageView yourimageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageView);

GlideDrawableImageViewTarget glideTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(yourimageView);

Glide.with(this)
.load(R.raw.gif)
.into(glideTarget);
```